# How to set delay dynamically in VBScript

Tags: file, vbscript, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I have a batch script which will write commands into .vbs file and executes it at the end.
The task of VBScript is to zip a file and delete the original file. Here's the code:

```
FOR %%c in (%1%filename*.*) DO ( 
REM zip file which is not of current date
ECHO "%%c"|FINDSTR "%CurrentDate%" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo Option Explicit >> zipIt.vbs
echo Dim FileToZip, Result >> zipIt.vbs
echo Dim oShell >> zipIt.vbs
echo Dim file >> zipIt.vbs
echo Dim oFileSys >> zipIt.vbs
echo Dim winShell >> zipIt.vbs
echo FileToZip = "%%c" >> zipIt.vbs
echo Result = "%%c.zip" >> zipIt.vbs
echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^) >> zipIt.vbs
echo Set oFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^) >> zipIt.vbs
echo Set file = oFileSys.CreateTextFile(Result, True^) >> zipIt.vbs
echo file.Write "PK" ^& Chr(5^) ^& Chr(6^) ^& String(18, 0^) >> zipIt.vbs
echo file.Close >> zipIt.vbs
echo Set file = nothing >> zipIt.vbs
echo set winShell = createObject("shell.application"^) >> zipIt.vbs
Timeout /T 10
echo winShell.namespace(Result^).CopyHere FileToZip >> zipIt.vbs
Timeout /T 10
echo wScript.Sleep(30000^) >> zipIt.vbs

REM Delete the file
echo oFileSys.DeleteFile FileToZip >> zipIt.vbs
CScript zipIt.vbs
```

The files to be zipped are of different sizes.
So it would be great not to wait for 30 seconds for a file of smaller size.

```
echo winShell.namespace(Result^).CopyHere FileToZip >> zipIt.vbs
Timeout /T 10
echo wScript.Sleep(30000^) >> zipIt.vbs

REM Delete the file
echo oFileSys.DeleteFile FileToZip >> zipIt.vbs
```

Sleep time is required for `CopyHere` method to copy the file into empty zip file created.

For example, if it takes 30 seconds to zip a file of size 500 MB, then I don't want the script to wait for 30 seconds when the file size is 100 MB.

Can we make the script to wait as much time required to zip a file? Is there any command or function in VBScript?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you always doing this on the same computer and is the content of the file you're zipping basically the same? If so, you could do some performance comparisons for zipping 100,200,300,400,ect meg files and set the sleep accordingly.

Comment: Always doing on the same computer. Pattern and content will be similar. There can be multiple files with different sizes.

Comment: Are you adding multiple files to a single zip or are you creating one zip file with 1 file in it?

Comment: Also, If it's a single zip file with just one file, is it the only file in the directory or are there other files in the same directory that are not being zipped?

Comment: There are many files in the directory which should not be zipped. Files with same pattern in their names `%1%filename*.*` are zipped. Each time `for` loop runs and adds single file in a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a sleep, CScript zipIt.vbs will run until all the files have been compressed.

However if you do run into timing issues, I would suggest that you take out the .DeleteFile from within the vbScript and do it in the batch script using the del utility.

Another solution would be to change the batch file into one big vbScript.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. If I don't give enough sleep, vbScript will throw a Permission denied error at this line:  `echo oFileSys.DeleteFile FileToZip >> zipIt.vbs`  and fails to delete the file. As you said let me try to do it in the batch script. Will come back soon with whatever I get.

Comment: What is rem utility you mentioned? I tried with `del "%%c"` It deletes the file as expected. But, the problem is, CScript does not wait for file to be compressed. It waits for Sleep time and returns to batch script. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need either a batch nor a vbs if you use winrar with the -m option which move all files at the end of the compression phase to the archve (so destroys the original). I know winrar is principle has to be paid and is often outperformed by modern zip implementations like 7zip but often it still is the best.

Comment: The script has to scheduled to run on Windows Server 2008 and there is no scope for using any third party tool. The task needs to be accomplished using windows built-in capabilities. Thanks for suggestion.